# I'm calculating the average of scores in a dictionary, but it returns error

Tags: python

I'm calculating the average of scores in a dictionary, but it returns an error and I don't know exactly what's the error:

[image]

Comment: Posting your question as an image just makes it harder for people to help you.  Post your question as text.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your code directly, and refrain from using indirect information such as links, images, etc.

Comment: Post directly your code not image, it can help to work on your problem...

Comment: You have an extra left square bracket on line 60.

Comment: Instead of picture of your code please provide the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) itself.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is above the `else` statement, there is an extra `[` it should be

```
dic[i[0]].append(int(i[1]))
```

Answer (score -1):

The line 60 of your code has an extra `[` bracket. It should be

`dict[i[0]].append(int(i[1]))`

PS. Do not post your questions on stack-overflow as images. It makes it harder to help. Have a look at other questions to understand how to post questions.